# Combine rows SQL Query specific

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I need some help on developing a query that will combine rows of the same client.  Basically I have a Client that has a Tax manager, an Audit manager, an account manager etc.

So far with the code I have used I am able to pull up the information but it spits out several rows of the same client for each type of manager

example on the picture (with the code and the result).  Right below I added a link, it wouldn't let me add a picture directly.

[Here is the link of the screenshot to get a better idea, it wouldn't let me add a picture here!!](http://imageshack.com/a/img689/5263/oti6.png)

The code is as follows:

```
select ocr.staffcode as OCR, clientcode, clientname, 
case when cs.ServIndex = 'TAXCOMP' then tax.StaffCode else '-' end as 'Tax',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'AUDIT' then audit.staffcode else '-' end as 'Audit',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'REVIEW' then review.staffcode else '-' end as 'Review',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'COMP' then comp.staffcode else '-' end as 'Comp',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'RandE' then rande.staffcode else '-' end as 'R&E',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'ACCTG' then acctg.staffcode else '-' end as 'Acctg',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'VMA' then vma.staffcode else '-' end as 'BV',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'LIT' then lit.staffcode else '-' end as 'Lit',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'FORENSIC' then lit.staffcode else '-' end as 'Forensics',
case when cs.ServIndex = 'CONS' then lit.staffcode else '-' end as 'Consulting'
from tblEngagement e
inner join tblClientServices cs on cs.ContIndex = e.contindex
left outer join tblStaff ocr on ocr.StaffIndex = e.ClientPartner
left outer join tblStaff tax on tax.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff audit on audit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff review on review.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff comp on comp.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff rande on rande.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff acctg on acctg.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff vma on vma.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff lit on lit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff fore on fore.staffindex = cs.ServManager
where e.ContIndex < 900000 and cs.ServActPos = 1 and ClientStatus in ('ACTIVE','SUSPENDED') 
order by ClientCode
```

I want to be able to just combine all those of the same OCR,Clietcode, Client Name to one row displaying the tax manager, audit manager, review manager, etc all in one row... if there is no manager for one of the just display a "-" as it does in my example.  I have been reading several places and trying to do myself but no luck. Anyone can help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your database MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag questions accordingly.

Comment: Look up `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I am running microsoft sql server management studio (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2) is that what you mean?

Comment: @user3195866 - then you should not have tagged this `mysql`.

Comment: I will remove it, sorry

Comment: I added a distinct next to the select and then below the order by I added a group by which reads as follows: group by ocr.staffcode as OCR, clientcode, clientname  but I get an error that there is a syntax error by "as"

Answer (score 0):

try grouping by the clients thus eliminating the duplicates, maxing the case columns and filling up the NULLs with '-' after that. however the code below will only show **one** manager per category. so should there be two audit managers, only one will be returned by this:

```
select ocr.staffcode as OCR, clientcode, clientname, 
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'TAXCOMP' then tax.StaffCode end),'-') as 'Tax',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'AUDIT' then audit.staffcode end),'-') as 'Audit',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'REVIEW' then review.staffcode end),'-') as 'Review',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'COMP' then comp.staffcode end),'-') as 'Comp',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'RandE' then rande.staffcode end),'-') as 'R&E',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'ACCTG' then acctg.staffcode end),'-') as 'Acctg',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'VMA' then vma.staffcode end),'-') as 'BV',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'LIT' then lit.staffcode end),'-') as 'Lit',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'FORENSIC' then lit.staffcode end),'-') as 'Forensics',
coalesce(max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'CONS' then lit.staffcode end),'-') as 'Consulting'
from tblEngagement e
inner join tblClientServices cs on cs.ContIndex = e.contindex
left outer join tblStaff ocr on ocr.StaffIndex = e.ClientPartner
left outer join tblStaff tax on tax.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff audit on audit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff review on review.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff comp on comp.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff rande on rande.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff acctg on acctg.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff vma on vma.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff lit on lit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
left outer join tblStaff fore on fore.staffindex = cs.ServManager
where e.ContIndex < 900000 and cs.ServActPos = 1 and ClientStatus in ('ACTIVE','SUSPENDED') 
group by ocr.staffcode, clientcode, clientname
order by ClientCode
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, just saw it, going to give it a try and get back to you!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works as it needs to, now just waiting to see if that is sufficient.  Also this code I wrote today works as well and is very similar without the "coalesce" could you explain to me why you used the coalesce?

Comment: i used the coalesce to put in `'-'` for missing values. the reason for that is because you had the `'-'` in the `else` branch of your `case`, essentially doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This code also works, very similar to Brett's above me

```
 select ocr.staffcode as OCR, clientcode, clientname, 
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'TAXCOMP' then tax.StaffCode else '-' end) as 'Tax',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'AUDIT' then audit.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Audit',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'REVIEW' then review.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Review',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'COMP' then comp.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Comp',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'RandE' then rande.staffcode else '-' end) as 'R&E',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'ACCTG' then acctg.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Acctg',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'VMA' then vma.staffcode else '-' end) as 'BV',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'LIT' then lit.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Lit',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'FORENSIC' then lit.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Forensics',
 max(case when cs.ServIndex = 'CONS' then lit.staffcode else '-' end) as 'Consulting'
 from tblEngagement e
 inner join tblClientServices cs on cs.ContIndex = e.contindex
 left outer join tblStaff ocr on ocr.StaffIndex = e.ClientPartner
 left outer join tblStaff tax on tax.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff audit on audit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff review on review.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff comp on comp.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff rande on rande.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff acctg on acctg.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff vma on vma.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff lit on lit.StaffIndex = cs.ServManager
 left outer join tblStaff fore on fore.staffindex = cs.ServManager
 where e.ContIndex < 900000 and cs.ServActPos = 1 and ClientStatus in ('ACTIVE','SUSPENDED') 
 group by ocr.staffcode, clientcode, clientname
 order by ClientCode
```

Thanks Brett